# Understanding BuildClusterTree of Seurat

Tags: seurat, single-cell, clustering

I am trying to understand how to use `BuildClusterTree` of Seurat to understand the relationship between clusters. Being from neither a bioinformatics or statistical background, I am not understating how to use it. I am have the following Clustertree plot. Can someone explain how to use this function to `merge cell type clusters`.

[image]